# What can be done when a publisher is much more faster that subscriber?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, publish-subscribe, tornado-redis

I have a publisher-subscriber model where user connects through websocket and subscribe to a channel. The publisher publishes messages at a rate of 3000 msgs/per second and the subscriber on the other can process 2000 msgs/per second so due to this delay on the subscriber end the rest of the messages are going in redis buffer. So even if i keep the publisher running for around 10 minutes and then stop it, the subscriber will still be processing the messages because the messages are there in the buffer and due to that there would be a lag and sending the messages to user will get delayed.

Publisher sample code -

```
import redis
import asyncio
import random
import time

def connectRedis():
    redisConn = redis.StrictRedis(host="127.0.0.1", port=6379)
    return redisConn

def publish():
    pubSub = connectRedis()
    channel = "FY-CH"
    clientIdStr = "FA"
    count = 1
    while True:
        numStr = random.randint(0,99)

        clientId = clientIdStr+"%s"%str(numStr)
        orderstr = 'orderUpdate|0|700|2073|%s|0|3572|W|1264268746|C|3668|%s|%s|1000000001283150|M|B|2|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|0|1.109500|0.000000|320012304041.000000|1|-1|0.000000|A|0.000000|0|B|A|C||||1|CONFIRMED||1||N|0.000000|B||N|N|AFKPY8N'%(clientId, clientId, clientId)
        pubSub.publish(channel, orderstr)
        print("Published for {}".format(clientId))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    publish()
```

Subscriber Sample Code -

```
class RedisSub():

    subscriberDict = None
    iwsSubsDict = None ## It will contain the connection objects of the user connected
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, arg):
        RedisSub.count      += 1
        self.channelList    = []
        self.redisCli       = tornadis.PubSubClient(host=127.0.0.1)
        if len(str(chanlName)) > 0:
            self.chanlName  = chanlName
        else:
            self.chanlName  = "Channel "+str(RedisSub.count)
        self.startRecv()

    @gen.coroutine
    def startRecv(self):
        while True:
            try:
                subMess = yield self.redisCli.pubsub_pop_message(SUBSCRIPTION_WAIT_TIME)
                logging.info("subMess:{}".format(subMess))
                if not subMess: ## When timeout happens this will return None
                    continue
                if not isinstance(subMess, list):
                    logging.error(subMess)
                    yield gen.Task(IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 2)## Avoide infinite loop
                    self.reSub()
                    continue


                if RedisSub.iwsSubsDict:
                    dataRxList = tornado.escape.to_unicode(subMess[2])
                    dataRxList = dataRxList.split("|")
                    logging.info(dataRxList)
                    if int(dataRxList[2]) <= 0: ## If message length is 0 then it is an invalid data
                        continue
                    userId = dataRxList[12]
                    if userId in RedisSub.iwsSubsDict:
                        logging.info(RedisSub.iwsSubsDict)
                        connDict = {}
                        for appId in RedisSub.iwsSubsDict[userId]:
                            connDict.update(RedisSub.iwsSubsDict[userId][appId])
                        for conn in connDict:
                            data = "|".join(map(str,dataRxList))
                            conn.write_message(data)
```

I am using tornado and tornadis and starting the subscriber before start the event loop itself.
If anyone can help me as to what else can be done in this or am i doing something wrong in the code?

Comment: So you've described the fact that your producer is faster than a consumer. But it's still not clear what your problem is and what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: @Fian What sort of optimisations can be done on the consumer side to overcome this issue of slow consumer?

Comment: Scale your consumer throughput up to match a producer. If data is produced faster than consumed there always would be buffer overflows or dropped data.